# Determine which gene is in the middle complementation

Tags: genetics, homework

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Crossing mutant strains on minimal media problem](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/2103/crossing-mutant-strains-on-minimal-media-problem)

I'm studying this problem for my genetics final:
[image]

**My Attempt:**   The answer for part B is met2 and the answer for part C is Df1.  Met2 and met 1 both have 1 no so i'm not sure how met2 is in the middle.  I didn't even know complementation tests could tell gene location. I think the answer to part C is because df1 has the most NOs, which means it's missing the most DNA.  (If it had that DNA, it would complement).

Comment: Please don't ask a duplicate question, you can just edit your own posts to add more information. I copied the content of this question into your older one, and will delete this one soon.